# What is this husk-like material in allegedly de-husked Carafa 3 Special?

Tags: specialty-malt

I'm brewing Black IPA. So I needed less bitter black malt. My choice was Carafa III Special - it is supposed to be de-husked kind. But it looks like this:
[image: Malt photo]

Brighter shot, close-up on thing that made me wonder:
[image: Closer look]

What is it? It looks kinda like husk pieces. But there should be no husk pieces in this malt. Does this malt always look like that, and what part of grain actually forms these flakes? Or maybe shopkeeper just made a mistake, as he weights and packs malts on demand.

Comment: Side note:  nice photos.

Comment: @ty733420 thanks. I try to make my questions worth people's while.

Answer (score 2):

**That's husk fragments**

Winnowing doesn't get 100% removal. Looks like the grain from the bottom of the bag to me.